# Transpose Group of Rows to Single Row | MS EXCEL

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2016, power-query

I need to Transform Some Uneven Group of multiple rows to single row

I Tried to Extract the Required data from multiple row to multiple Column. But all data placed under different Rows (same as input rows).

but I need the Result in single Row as per below snap. Kindly suggest your ideas...

```
seq.    Criteria
1   Numbers Only
2   1st charater  = Text & last  charater =Number, charater Length = 14 to 20
3   Always 3rd Row, Last charater is Letter
4   First charater = "["
5   First 2 Character = "XY"
6   Must contain the word = "Quantity"
7   Criteria 1 = <> "['   & Criteria 2 = 4th row value in each data set
8   if Helper column had the word = "Replace"



ID  Data    sequence
10  10  1
10  A1  2
10  A2  3
10  A3  4
10  A4  5
10  A5  6
10  A6  7
10  A7  8
20  20  1
20  B1  2
20  B2  3
20  B3  4
20  B4  5
20  B5  6
20  B6  7
20  B7  8
30  30  1
30  C1  2
30  C2  3
30  C3  4
30  C8  5
30  30  1
30  D1  2
30  D2  3
30  D3  4
30  D4  5
30  D5  6
30  D6  7



Required output                             
10  A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6  A7  A8
20  B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  B6  B7  B8
30  C1  C2  C3                  C8
30  D1  D2  D3  D4  D5  D6
```

[image]

***Sample Format***

**Mandatory Data:**

1. S.NO. 2. Part#  3. Quantity

**Optional Data:** (Sometimes it will blanks)

1. Description  2.Notes 3. Group    4. Replacements 5. Section

So the input row data will change dynamically

[image]

Comment: Seems like adding a helper column to determine what column your `Row Value` belongs to (for instance what is it about B8 and C8 makes it belong in data9), then a pivot table should get you to your end result.

Comment: Pivot table combined the duplicate value, but i need output with duplicate value

Comment: Just to make sure, something like this would not be any help for you https://i.imgur.com/zf8SEjF.png?

Comment: yeah sorry I forgot excel pivot requires an aggregation. Since you mention power query I'm sure you can do this in there. As long as you can 1) as above specify how row value belongs to different columns, 2) how you can distinguish different "duplicates" (30) and then 3) pivot using the "don't aggregate" option.

Comment: Will the row values in your original data always end with the column number? If not, how do you tell that `C8` goes into the 8th column and not the fourth column?

Comment: @YisroelTech 3rd output skipped the blanks. I need Blank column if the particular value missing.

Comment: @ron-rosenfeld I am using Criteria based formula for each column. So the value must seat over the respective column..

Comment: I cannot apply that information. Again, how do you know that `C8` goes into column 8 and not column 4?

Comment: check the updated question pls

Comment: Your criteria are helpful, although need some adjustments as some entries will respond to more than one. However, none of your criteria match with the "Notes" column.  And `seq 7` makes no sense to me.

Comment: Sorry the Notes will come in 4th Row. Its optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac), and designed to "shape data"

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

*I wrote a custom function to determine the type of data. However, you don't really have a defined type for "Notes", so I just used that for any format that did not fall into any of the other patterns*

*For the custom function, once you are in the Power Query Editor, right click in the Queries window to create a new query; rename it as it states in the code (See Properties=>Name in the right pane)*

*Please note that PQ is case sensitive. Code will need to be altered if you need it to be case-insensitive (eg if you might have both `Quantity` and `QUANTITY` in your data)*

***Custom Function***

```
//Rename fnPattern

(val as any)=>

let
    txt = Text.From(val),
    Source = Text.ToList(txt),
    

//S. No
    seq1 = List.AllTrue(List.Transform(Source, each not (try Number.From(_))[HasError])),

//Part #
    seq2 = not List.AllTrue(List.Transform(Source, each not (try Number.From(_))[HasError]))
            and not (try Number.From(List.Last(Source)))[HasError]
            and List.Count(Source) >=14
            and List.Count(Source) <=20
            and not Text.Contains(txt,"Replace")
            and not Text.StartsWith(txt,"XY"),

//Description
    seq3 = List.Contains({"A".."Z"}, List.Last(Source)),

//Group
    seq4 = List.First(Source) = "[",

//Section
    seq5 = Text.StartsWith(txt,"XY"),

//Qty
    seq6 = Text.Contains(txt, "Quantity"),

//?
    seq7 = null, 

//Replace
    seq8 = Text.Contains(txt,"Replace"),

    seq = {seq1,seq2,seq3,seq4,seq5,seq6,seq7,seq8},
    colNames = {"S.NO","Part#","Description","Group","Section","Qty","Notes","Replacements"},
    colName = try colNames{List.PositionOf(seq,true)} otherwise "Notes"
    
in
   colName
```

***Main Query***

```
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Parts"]}[Content],

//Call custom function to determine type of entry
#"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Col", each fnPattern([Input]), type text),

//Assume that first line for EVERY group is the S.NO
//Add a column to group each set of data
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Invoked Custom Function", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Grouper", each if [Col] = "S.NO" then [Index] else null),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Index"}),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Removed Columns",{"Grouper"}),

//Group by each data set
//then Pivot each subgroup (with no aggreagation
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Down", {"Grouper"}, {
        {"Pivot", each Table.Pivot(Table.RemoveColumns(_,"Grouper"), List.Distinct(_[Col]), "Col","Input" ),
            type table[S.NO=Int64.Type, #"Part#"= text, Description=text, Replacements=text, Group=text, Section=text, Qty=text, Notes=text]
        } }),

//remove unneeded column
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Grouper"}),

//expand the column of pivoted tables
//then re-arrange the columns into the desired order
    #"Expanded Pivot" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "Pivot", 
        {"S.NO", "Part#", "Description", "Replacements", "Group", "Section", "Qty", "Notes"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Expanded Pivot",
        {"S.NO", "Part#", "Description", "Notes", "Group", "Replacements", "Section", "Qty"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

***Input***
[image]

***Output***
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the code, Ron. I really want to learn your code, too bad my Excel is 2010 :(.

Comment: @karma Power query is available as a free addin from Microsoft for XL2010

Comment: Oh ok... I will try to download it and install that addin. Thanks for the information, Ron.

Comment: I removed the word from the Code : Int64.Type   Then it was working without any issue..   ---------------                                                           
The Error is :   Expression.Error: 5 arguments were passed to function which expects between 2 and 4.
Details:
    Pattern=                                          
    Arguments=List    -------------                                                                                                                        Thank you very much @Ron,,, Without any helper column it will very much helpful for me...

Comment: @baskar Glad it is working for you. But I'm surprised about the error since the code runs without error here. From which step did you remove `Int64.Type`

Comment: Added Index column mentioned with Int64.Type. I get error in this line, So i removed it. Currently I am using office 365 based Excel

Comment: @baskar I wonder if it could be a version difference. MS documentation for [Table.AddIndexColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-addindexcolumn) clearly shows two required + 3 optional arguments, with the last one being the `columntype`. And also it works here with no error.

Comment: @baskar Apparently that fifth argument was added to the `Table.AddIndexColumn` function a few years ago. I find something referring the "newly added" columntype argument in a post from 2020. So if you are using the PQ from the add-in for Excel 2010, that would explain why you received that error.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the kind of your situation....

[image]

Since it's not so clear how is the pattern for "screw/nut" and "m10x25" (yellow filled), so I just add the input data with "Desc" and "Note" in order it can be applied to meet the condition.

The sub assumes that under INPUT column the first data value will always is A NUMBER and the last data value will always NOT A NUMBER. Within the data set itself the first value is a number and the rest is NOT A NUMBER.

Example :
5,A0076...34,Desc:bla,[test]...47,quant:123,replace:blo,XY:123 ---> Correct data set because it always start with a row with number then the next row is not a number.

11,replace:blo,[zzz] ... 14,23,Desc ---> Incorrect data set because there are two consecutive rows with number value (14 and 23).

A23,Quantity:3,Desc... 10,[yyy],XY=456 ---> Incorrect data set because it doesn't start with number (A23).

```
Sub test()

'addr = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)) _
'    .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlNumbers).Address

For Each cell In Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))
If Application.IsNumber(cell.Value) Then addr = addr & "," & cell.Address
Next
addr = Right(addr, Len(addr) - 1)

cnt = Len(addr) - Len(Application.Substitute(addr, ",", "")) + 1

Set rgR = Range("c" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

For i = 1 To cnt

    If i = cnt Then
        Set rgC = Range(Split(addr, ",")(i - 1))
        Set rgC = Range(rgC, rgC.End(xlDown))
    Else
        Set rgC = Range(Split(addr, ",")(i - 1), Split(addr, ",")(i))
        Set rgC = rgC.Resize(rgC.Rows.Count - 1, 1)
    End If
    'rgC.select 'uncomment to see the result of rgC when step run
    For Each cell In rgC
        Select Case True
        Case InStr(cell.Value, "Replace"): rgR.Offset(0, 5).Value = cell.Value
        Case Left(cell.Value, 2) = "XY": rgR.Offset(0, 6).Value = cell.Value
        Case application.isnumber(cell.Value): rgR.Value = cell.Value
        Case InStr(cell.Value, "["): rgR.Offset(0, 4).Value = cell.Value
        Case InStr(cell.Value, "Quantity") = False And _
                InStr(cell.Value, "XY") = False And _
                InStr(cell.Value, "Note") = False And _
                application.isnumber(Left(cell.Value, 1)) = False And _
                application.isnumber(Right(cell.Value, 1)) = True
            rgR.Offset(0, 1).Value = cell.Value
        Case InStr(cell.Value, "Quantity"): rgR.Offset(0, 7).Value = cell.Value
        Case InStr(cell.Value, "Note"): rgR.Offset(0, 3).Value = cell.Value
        Case InStr(cell.Value, "Desc"): rgR.Offset(0, 2).Value = cell.Value
        End Select
    Next
    
Set rgR = rgR.Offset(1, 0)
Next i

End Sub
```

addr is the address for each cell with number value.
cnt is the count of how many cells are there in addr.
rgR is the starting cell to put the result.

Then it loop from 1 to as many as the cnt, make the rgC which is the range of the set. Then it loop within the rgC, checking the looped cell value meet which case, then put the looped cell value according to which column.

The case to put the value (of the looped cell) to which column output :
number ---> col C
contains "replace" ---> col H
contains "quantity" ---> col J
start with "[" ---> col G
contains "desc" ---> col E
start with "XY" ---> col I
start with letter end with number but not contains "XY" not contains "replace" not contains "note" not contains "quantity" ---> col D
contains "note" ---> column F

Comment: Thank you, the code was working.  But The Column B is not a unique format "as you understand the Format is not only Start with Text and end with number".        
   I have 8 different Combination of Format for each data set.

Comment: I edited my question for more clarity.

Comment: @baskar, sorry I don't understand what you mean. How is your data look in column B in reality ? Something like this ? Exampl : cell A2:A6 value is 10. Cell B2 value `a1234567891234`, cell B3 value `[blablabla`, cell B4 value `replace apple to orange`, cell B5 value `1234567`, cell B6 value `the quantity is 10`. Expected result : cell E2 value `10`, cell F2 value `1234567`, cell G2 value `a1234567891234`, cell H2 blank, cell i2 value `[blablabla`, cell j2 blank, cell K2 value `the quantity is 10`, cell L2 blank, cell M2 value `replace apple to orange`. Please CMIIW.

Comment: Also, maybe it will be better if you show various of data value on each condition from those 8 conditions besides describing it from 1 to 8.

Comment: Pls check the updated Question.

Comment: @baskar, please have a look to my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you Very much .... Its working....

Comment: This code had a limitation  (addr) declaration - 39 address only processed

Comment: `IsNumeric` will return `True` for strings that resemble scientific format.  eg `12E67`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, thank you for the information. I will change it to `IsNumber`.

Comment: @baskar, I am sorry ... maybe there is character limitation for string (dim addr as string), that's why it only get 39 address.

Comment: The same is true for that function. You need to check each character individually to avoid that issue.

Comment: @karma IsNumber - worksheet function, it will not work on VBA

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, thank you for your advice. I will try to get the addr by looping and check each cell.

Comment: @baskar, I think we still can use it if we put application. in front of the isnumber ? Please CMIIW. Please have a look to the revised code for addr in my answer.

Comment: @Karma Thank you very much, Now its working... without any limitations.